# Extract version number from a comment

Tags: php, regex

I have a CSS (or HTML or JS) file with a comment `/* Version: 1.2.1 */` near the beginning of the file.

Using PHP/regex, how do I get a string containing `'1.2.1'`?

I apologise for not RTFM but I can't find an answer on the Google. Any direction on learning regex would be great!

Comment: are you looking for this? http://docs.phpdoc.org/guides/docblocks.html

Comment: `^\/\**.Version: (.*)\*\/` or something like that. Try something like regex101.com

Comment: You could try [`\/\* Version: (\d\.\d\.\d) \*\/`](https://regex101.com/r/QbTpBb/1) and the version number will be in the first captured group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '/* Version 1.2.1 */';
preg_match('/version\s(.*)\s\*/i',$str,$matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

> its very simple to grap, `\s(.*)\s` capture anything in between
>   `spaces` as first group. display first captured group `$matches[1]`

if you are curious that how it works or wanna learn yourself ? you can dive directly into it from here i found this very helpful for beginner.

[Regular Expressions!](https://ryanstutorials.net/regular-expressions-tutorial/)

[DIY](https://regex101.coma)

Comment: This works exactly the way I was looking for! Thanks! And thanks for the links.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with regex learning, I strongly recommend these two sites:

- [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/)
- [Regular-Expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/index.html)

To test your regex [regex101](https://regex101.com/) is particularly usefull.

---

That being said, you have two options to consider:

1. You want to work with a capture group.
2. You want to get only a match.

If you can work with a capture group, simple regex will work:

```
^\s*\/\* Version: (\d\.\d\.\d) \*\/
```

This will capture the version number in group 1 ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/435Ryn/1)).

When you want to only get the matching version number but don't want to bother with a capture group, you have to work with lookarounds:

- A lookbehind allows you to check for text preceding the match. In your case: `(?<=\/\* Version: )`.
- A lookafter to check for the comment end: `(?= \/\*)`.

Assembled with version number matching ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/435Ryn/2)):

```
(?<=\/\* Version: )\d\.\d\.\d(?= \*\/)
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome links! Hopefully, I won't need to ask other people to write my RegEx for me again!!